# An error occured (InvalidClientTokenId) when calling... (AWS)

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-iam

I am getting this error: "An error occurred (InvalidClientTokenId) when calling the DetachRolePolicy operation: The security token included in the request is invalid." when running this command: "aws iam detach-role-policy --role-name "roleName" --policy-arn "policy-arn" in the aws cloudshell.

I am trying to detach a policy from a specific role and I am getting this error. I was expecting for the policy to be detached but I keep getting this error.

Answer (score 1):

I solved the issue. If you are using AWS cloudshell within your AWS account, you do not need to do AWS configure to configure your session. In fact if you run aws configure, you will most likely mess up something in the backlogs of your session.

If you ran aws configure and now your cloudshell is giving you the same error as what I was receiving, go to the actions dropdown on the top right of the cloudshell window pane, and click on Delete AWS Cloudshell Home Directory. This will completely reset your session, simply restarting your session may not work.

Comment: I did this EXACT same thing. Thanks for the answer.